# How to link a scatter plot generated using datashade with an RGB image In Holoviews?

Tags: python, holoviews

I have a satellite image, based on this image I need to produce a scatter plot between two bands ( eg. red vs green ), be able to select data on this plot and see the selection on the satellite image.

So far, I have produce the scatter plot using hv.scatter and datashade, and I have display my satellite image as an RGB image.

```
im_data = hv.RGB(stack_array8, bounds = bounds)
scatter = hv.Scatter(bands_df, 'band4', 'band5')
ds_scatter = datashade(scatter)
```

How can a link these two plots in Holoviews?

I have tried :im_data + ds_scatter, but it's not possible. Once the datashade is introduced, the sets of data have different dimensions and it's not possible to link them . Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you use something like the approach in https://anaconda.org/jbednar/glaciers/notebook?

Comment: I have been trying the approach suggested, however I can't seem to find a way to create an RGB image from a   dataframe.

Comment: I have created my dataset :                          data_image =  hv.Dataset(df_coord, ['lon','lat'],['band3','band4','band5'])   and I can create my scatter plot perfectly  with :datashade(data_image.to(hv.Scatter, 'band4','band5',[]).options(**scat_opts))                                            but I can't figure out how to plot my RGB image .                                          hv.RGB is expecting gridded data and I don't seem to be able to transform the columns from my data_image into gridded data.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Depends how your data is stored; images are by nature gridded and normally they are read into a gridded data structure first, so I would guess you already have that before you put it into Pandas?  If so use that.  If not, you can convert it to an xarray grid using something like https://github.com/pyviz/holoviews/issues/3686 .

Comment: I don't think I summarised  my problem properly before. As you mentioned I have transformed my satellite image into a numpy array before I stored it as a data frame. I want to use holoviews to plot my satellite image as an RGB and link it to a scatter plot made out of two bands of the same image, so I can select data on my scatter plot and see it reflected on my image. I can plot my scatter plot using a data frame and an RGB image using a numpy array, but my understanding is that  to link the image and the plot they need to have the same data source. Am I correct in my approach?

Comment: Ah, got it.  You're basically wanting to treat the same dataset as both an approximation to a continuous surface (for which hv.Image is appropriate) and as a set of samples (for which a dataframe is appropriate), at the same time. I don't know how I'd try to do that. :-(